# Correct way to use static parameters in Android

Tags: java, android

I am pretty new in Android and I do not know how is the proper way to manage static constants. I mean, I need to use several constants (such as `COMMAND_BACK = 100`) in several Java classes and activities. It is not beautiful to declare them as attributes in each single activity so, what is the correct way to do this?

I though about declaring them in `strings.xml`, but it does not seem suitable neither...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a common class for Contants in that case

Comment: @MRX Could you illustrate that with an example?

Comment: what's not to understand? public static final int COMMAND_BACK = 100; refer to it with Classname.COMMAND_BACK

Comment: Make a common class for all of your static constant and final static.

Comment: 1. create a class, say `Constants.class`. 
2. Create variables like `public static final VARIABLE_NAME = <value>;`
3. You can access the variable in any class like: 
`Constants.VARIABLE_NAME`.

Comment: you need to defne the class of constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a class like this :

```
 public final class AppConstants {
    //put all the constant here
    // Eg :
   public static final int SPLASH_TIME = 1000;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantage by declaring it in a resource.xml file is that you need a context to receive the value. This is fine as long as you need those values inside a context class otherwise you have to pass one around.

The elegant solution would be extending the `Application` class since the android os itself uses static fields that way.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Constants class to the project

```
public class Constants {   
    public static final String STRING1 = "First String";
    public static final String STRING2 = "Second String";
    public static final int INTEGER1 = 1;
    public static final float FLOAT1 = 0.1f;  
}


// Use
textView.setText(Constants.STRING1);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Declare**

```
public final  class ConstantClass {

    public final static  int  COMMAND_BACK = 100;
}
```

**Usage**

```
int num = ConstantClass.COMMAND_BACK;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a common interface where you can declare all the constants.Constants can further be grouped here to make it mode clean.

```
 public interface Constants {
  public interface XYZ{
        public static final int A= 1; 
        public static final int B= 2; 
    }

    public interface REPORT_TYPE_FLAGS{
        public static final String C= "0";
        public static final String D= "1";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another elegant way is to define a constant class with other inner subclasses

```
`private final class Constant {

 public static class TypeOne {
     public static final String NAME = "Type 1";
     public static final int CODE = 1;
 }

 public static class TypeTwo {
     public static final String NAME = "Type 2";
     public static final int CODE = 2;
 }
}
```

`

And you can access it in this way

```
`String typeOneName = Constant.TypeOne.NAME;
 int typeTwoCode = Constant.TypeTwo.CODE;
`
```